# LVS is not accessible from the outside

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, linux-virtual-server

I'm currently busy setting up a [LVS - Linux Virtual Server](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/):

```
root@debian1:~# ipvsadm -L
IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size=4096)
Prot LocalAddress:Port Scheduler Flags
  -> RemoteAddress:Port           Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
TCP  debian1.lan:http wlc
  -> debian2.lan:http             Masq    1      0          1         
  -> debian3.lan:http             Masq    1      0          1
```

debian1.lan is my VIP. debian2 and 3 are running apache.

I'm able to use `curl` to get content:

```
root@debian1:~# curl debian1.lan
<html><body><h1>debian2</h1>
<p>This is the default web page for this server.</p>
<p>The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.</p>
</body></html>
```

But when I access debian1.lan (10.0.0.171) using `firefox` from my windows computer I get a "The connection has timed out" message.

Is it maybe possible that Virtualbox is messing up the LVS? (debian 1 to 3 are VM's in Virtualbox using a bridged adapter).

I started `tcpdump` on my debian2 and I see packets (when I use `firefox`) although I'm not sure about the meaning:

```
root@debian2:~# tcpdump -s 0 -A tcp port http
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
13:07:05.725727 IP My-PC.lan.54663 > debian2.lan.http: Flags [S], seq 1738645408, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
E..4.M@....-
...
......Pg......... .\...............
13:07:05.725755 IP debian2.lan.http > My-PC.lan.54663: Flags [S.], seq 184008166, ack 1738645409, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 4], length 0
E..4..@.@.%{
...
....P..
...g.....9..p..............
13:07:06.722025 IP debian2.lan.http > My-PC.lan.54663: Flags [S.], seq 184008166, ack 1738645409, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 4], length 0
E..4..@.@.%{
...
....P..
...g.....9..p..............
13:07:08.722729 IP debian2.lan.http > My-PC.lan.54663: Flags [S.], seq 184008166, ack 1738645409, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 4], length 0
E..4..@.@.%{
...
....P..
...g.....9..p..............
13:07:08.723841 IP My-PC.lan.54663 > debian2.lan.http: Flags [S], seq 1738645408, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
E..4.a@.....
...
......Pg......... .\...............
13:07:08.723849 IP debian2.lan.http > My-PC.lan.54663: Flags [S.], seq 184008166, ack 1738645409, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 4], length 0
E..4..@.@.%{
...
....P..
...g.....9..p..............
13:07:12.722808 IP debian2.lan.http > My-PC.lan.54663: Flags [S.], seq 184008166, ack 1738645409, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 4], length 0
E..4..@.@.%{
...
....P..
...g.....9..p..............
13:07:14.724158 IP My-PC.lan.54663 > debian2.lan.http: Flags [S], seq 1738645408, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
E..0.g@.....
...
......Pg.......p. .p...........
13:07:14.724179 IP debian2.lan.http > My-PC.lan.54663: Flags [S.], seq 184008166, ack 1738645409, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 4], length 0
E..4..@.@.%{
...
....P..
...g.....9..p..............
13:07:20.722805 IP debian2.lan.http > My-PC.lan.54663: Flags [S.], seq 184008166, ack 1738645409, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 4], length 0
E..4..@.@.%{
...
....P..
...g.....9..p..............
```

Can somebody offer me a helping hint on what I may do or check next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this working. The solution was to create an entirely new private network for the real servers in the LVS, I used 192.168.1.x (of course the director also needs access to this network). For the VIP I used my public IP address 10.0.0.x . In addition I had to remove any trace from my old network (10.0.0.x) from the real servers in my LVS.

```
root@debian1:~# ipvsadm -L --stats
IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size=4096)
Prot LocalAddress:Port               Conns   InPkts  OutPkts  InBytes OutBytes
  -> RemoteAddress:Port
TCP  debian1.lan:http                   45      269      167    27483    27061
  -> 192.168.1.2:http                   21      118       74    11370    11912
  -> 192.168.1.3:http                   24      151       93    16113    15149
```

Hopefully this helps somebody with the same problem.